# Как исправить ошибку с sqlite3 в Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu, sqlite3

Не могу победить sqlite3 на Ubuntu server.
Есть тестовый проект (который в Windows работает нормально). При попытке запуска проекта Django вылетает с ошибкой, связанной с sqlite3.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
    create_deterministic_function('django_date_extract', 2, _sqlite_datetime_extract)
sqlite3.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gourii/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
    create_deterministic_function('django_date_extract', 2, _sqlite_datetime_extract)
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
```

Версия sqlite3:

```
3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12 a611fa96c4a848614efe899130359c9f6fb889c3
```

Перепробовал кучу вариантов решений из интернета ([например 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500117/how-to-fix-error-django-db-utils-notsupportederror-uris-not-supported)), ничего не помогает.
Скорее всего проблема в Питоне. Потому что версия sqlite3 в нем другая:

```
Python 3.8.6 (default, Dec 12 2020, 08:29:04)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 11, 0)
```

Comment: `>>> sqlite3.version '2.6.0'`, тогда как `requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher`.

Answer (score 1):

Обновите версию SQLite. Потому что determenistic это "новая" опция:

> This flag is supported by SQLite 3.8.3 or higher, NotSupportedError will be raised if used with older versions.

[Источник](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Также можете посмотреть ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674176/django-cant-find-new-sqlite-version-sqlite-3-8-3-or-later-is-required-found), у вас явно какая-то путаница в Python'е

Comment: Версию sqlite3 обновил, теперь такая: 3.34.0 2020-12-01 16:14:00 a26b6597e3ae272231b96f9982c3bcc17ddec2f2b6eb4df06a224b91089fed5b.

Comment: Теперь работает?

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: @Gourii вам команда sqlite3.version вывела номер версии?

Comment: Python 3.8.6 (default, Dec 12 2020, 08:29:04)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.11.0'

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема.
Решил тем что установил в систему актуальную sqlite3 и перекомпилировал Python из исходников. Таким образом актуальный sqlite включился в сборку Python.

Возможно есть другие варианты, этот для меня оказался самым быстрым.